# Wordpress UTC timezone is wrong

Tags: timezones

I have this kind of issue and I hope that somebody can help me. First of all if I want to publish a POST or PAGE, my content is scheduled and the post is published 1 hour later. If I want to change the hour, I Edit the post and I see this.

[image]

I think this issue is due to UTC time. I already checked everything. I installed a plugin called Scheduled Post Trigger but is not solving my problem.

After that I checked the hour set in WordPress and it looks like this
[image]

My php.ini it's okay and the time of server also.

This is how it looks in my local server
[image]

and this is how it looks in the remote server
[image]

I use PHP 7.3 and WordPress 5.3

Comment: the problem is the time configuration of your remote server, If your are in Spain it's UTC+1, then you should see "universal time 12:49 local time 13:49" as you see it on the local server.

Comment: Also, when you're outputting the date in php, make sure to use `gmdate()` & not `date()`

Comment: @Andrew did you solve this?